# Browser forcibly sending multipart/formdata

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm sending a post request from the browser using the fetch API. This is my code:

```
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

fetch('/signup', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: new FormData(document.querySelector('form')),
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  headers
}).then(
  response => response.text()
).then(
  text => console.log(text)
);
```

My form contains text, email and password input types only. I was expecting the form data to be sent with the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded, however it's getting sent as multipart/formdata.

I have tried manually setting the headers on the fetch request and explicitly specifying the encType property of the form (even though it should be url-encoded by default) but it's not working.

This happens on both Chrome and Safari. I could easily work around this by using JSON, but I really want to know why this happens!

Comment: Can you post the code of you trying to set the header of the request? Another thing is that it is not supported in many of the major browsers yet. So it might be buggy still. See this table for compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#body-mixin):

> Switch on object's type:
>
> FormData
>
> Set action to an action that runs the multipart/form-data encoding algorithm, with object as form data set and with utf-8 as the explicit character encoding.
>
> Set Content-Type to `multipart/form-data;boundary=`, followed by the multipart/form-data boundary string generated by the multipart/form-data encoding algorithm.

It uses multipart because you are passing a FormData object and that is what fetch does with FormData objects.

---

If you want to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data then encode it that way manually or use an object that implements the  URLSearchParams interface.

You shouldn't need to though. `multipart/form-data` is a standard, and I've never come across a form data parsing library that can't handle it. The only negative you should have is that it makes the request take up slightly more bytes.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, express' [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) doesn't support multipart forms.

Comment: @AhmedA.Ghoneim — But it recommends 4 parsers that do.